# iPad mini 'memory' section not showing on xcode 5

Tags: xcode, debugging

I don't seem to have this problem when I use other iPads so I wonder if there's anything I can do about it. In the 'debug navigator' category, I can only see FPS of my running application, while with other devices I also see CPU and memory.

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Is this related to iOS version ?

Comment: @sage444 sorry, forgot to add that information: this iPad mini is using iOS6. I'm (almost) certain that the other devices which do show memory there were using 6 as well (though I will go and make sure now)

Comment: @sage444 mmm, I just tried and iPad2 with iOS6 and its not showing memory... it really could be related to iOS version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Performance Analyzer can show CPU load for iOS 6+, memory load available from iOS 7, this feature can be configured in scheme editor: 
[image: Scheme config]